# How to create a custom collection function to modify model data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have a model called `Presence` that stores user's presences as recurring events, where each row has a `start` and `end` date, a frequency, and an interval. In that way, I can use 
[RRule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule) to create events from a single database row.

Now when I fetch the data like `Presence::all()` I want to add a `->toRrule()` (like the `->toArray()`) so that the final data is modified to be a list of single events.

E.g.:

```
+----+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| id |   start    |    end     | interval | frequency |
+----+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-03 |        1 | DAILY     |
+----+------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

I would get this row with `Presence::first()` and I want to get the following with `Presence::all()->toRrule()`:

```
[
   [
      'start' => '2022-10-01'
      'end' => '2022-10-01'
   ],
   [
      'start' => '2022-10-02'
      'end' => '2022-10-02'
   ],
   [
      'start' => '2022-10-03'
      'end' => '2022-10-03'
   ],
]
```

Regardless of what the actual function does, a) is this an elegant way? and b) how and especially where do I create this function?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the best way to do this is to create a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) to transform

Comment: I added a more details example. With that, I am not sure if the resource is the right solution, because it is not a one to one "modification" it is a one to many "modification". And.... I'm not using the API, I only use the web routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into the path of optimizing the design of your solution.
Laravel offers a way to have custom collection for your Presence model, and there you can define your toRule() function. And it will be exactly in the way you are searching for.
Find the official doc here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections#custom-collections

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot tell if it is an elegant way since you did not specify what the function does.

You should add this function in your Model file. Now for the `Presence` model, you should head to the file `app/models/Presence.php` then add the function this way:

```
public static function toRrule() {
...
}
```

Now if you want to access the function on the `Presence` model, you simply do it this way `Presence::all()->toRrule()`

Comment: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::toRrule does not exist.` The function for example takes a start and end datetime and for every single day it creates an extra event

Comment: that is because of the typo ```toRule``` instead of ```toRrule```. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Innovin your current implementation adds a method to the model and **NOT** the collection returned by `->all()` call so when the OP tries `Presence::all()->toRule()`, they will always have an error because `->all()` returns a collection not a single model (even if only one item is present in the returned result) and that collection doesn't have `toRule` method. As suggested in the comments above, creating a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) seems the right way to go about it.

Comment: @ths I see. Well OP, go ahead with creating a [resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) instead.